# Flutter - InkWell not reacting to onTap inside Flexible

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, dart, flutter

I am trying to figure out, why the `onTap()` method inside my InkWell is not working. The InkWell widget is inside a `Flexible` widget. This `Flexible` widget is also inside 
a `Row`.

Here is my code:

```
TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();

@override
void dispose(){
    super.dispose();
    controller.dispose();
}

@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Card(        
        child: Container(          
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(                
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () => print("Search"), //Is not printing anything
                  child: TextField(                    
                    controller: controller,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: "Searching..."
                    ),                 
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(8.0)
            ),
          ),
        ),     
      );
    }
```

I do not know how to solve my problem. It would be awesome, if somebody would be able to solve it XD.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Wrapping `IgnorePointer` inside the Inkwell's child will solve this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () => print("Search"), //Is not printing anything
                child: IgnorePointer(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: controller,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: "Searching..."
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(8.0)
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: No Issue, Thanks

Comment: Inkwell wasn't working for me inside a bottom sheet, but adding this worked. Could someone explain why this happens and why this solution works?

Comment: In mine case, it is not working working inside stack -> positioned -> row -> container ... adding the ignore pointer also doesn't benefit. What can be the issue ?

Comment: Thanks! That was driving me craaaaazy ...

Comment: @AliYarKhan I had the same question.  For me, specifically I was positioning a close button outside the bounds of the Stack's parent.  For optimization, if the parent's hit test fails, none of the children are tested.

See this bug report for more context: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/104519

Comment: Did nothing for me