# Flutter - Ontap InkWell doesn't work inside Stack

Tags: flutter

I start with flutter and I have a problem using onTap ().

I used adobeXd to make my templates but It seems that I can't put GestureDetector and InkWell widgets.

```
Transform.translate(
        offset: Offset(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 30, 132.0),
        child:
        Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.7, 1.0),
              child:
              InkWell(
                onTap: (){
                  setState(() {
                    actu = true;
                  });
                  print('ink');

                },
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.85,
                      height: 36.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(19.0),
                        color: const Color(0x35ffffff),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Transform.translate(
                      offset: Offset(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.7, 6.0),
                      child:
                      // Adobe XD layer: 'Icones/actualiser' (component)
                      XDIconesactualiser(),
                    ),
                    Transform.translate(
                      offset: Offset(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 21.47, MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 110),
                      child:
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 75.0,
                        height: 27.0,
                        child: Text(
                          'Actualiser',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'OpenSans-SemiBold',
                            fontSize: 14,
                            color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

The onTap does not work. It seems that is when it's inside a Stack or a Transform.
Can you help me  ?

Edit :

the event is not triggered. Nothing happens as if it did not exist. When I look at the tree in the dev tool, the inkwell appears but when I click on the phone nothing happens

[The image of my Flutter tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ryh4.png)

Edit 2 :

I would like a structure like that

[image: Expected]

but when I deactivate the offset for the click to work. i get that

[image: Reality]

Comment: What does it means "it doesn't work?". What do you expect to happen and what actually happen?

Comment: the event is not triggered. Nothing happens as if it did not exist. When I look at the tree in the dev tool, the inkwell appears but when I click on the phone nothing happens

Comment: Do you mean you don't get the ink animation effect on tap?

Comment: at the beginning I used an onPressed gestureDectetor to trigger a function but it didn't work so I decided to use an InkWell

Comment: So the inkwell animation is working, and it's just the function that's being called in the `onTap` event? I've duplicated your code, and it works OK for me. If it's the inkwell animation you can't see, I know how to fix that.

Comment: No, there is no animation. nothing

Comment: this is a real issue when u offset the inkwell, or a gesture detector widget inside a stack. anyone got a workaround for it ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem too, turns out the solution is change `the orders of items in stacks`.

The `Ink Well` widget is covered with the `next Stack` element.

Move your `Ink Well` widget to the `last` of the `Stack` children.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. Wrapping Inkwell's child inside an `IgnorePointer` solved the issue.

Solved here: [Flutter - InkWell not reacting to onTap inside Flexible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52997295/flutter-inkwell-not-reacting-to-ontap-inside-flexible/52997409#52997409)

Answer (score 1):

If it's the inkwell animation you need, remove the `BoxDecoration` from the `Container` widget (or remove altogether if only used for the decoration), and wrap the inner `Stack` within an `Ink` widget with the color set to your original box decoration color. This worked for me.

```
child: Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Transform.translate(
      offset: Offset(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.7, 1.0),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            actu = true;
          });
          print('ink');
        },
        child: Ink(
          color: const Color(0x35ffffff),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.85,
                  height: 36.0,
                ),
        ...
```

Comment: I understand the problem but i don't know how to solve it. 
the problem comes from offset. it moves the visual elements but not the box where we click so it is hidden behind another element. if I delete the offet it works. How do I move the onTap box?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to the widget structure you're trying to do. Why do you want to move the visual elements? Are you saying that you want 2 tap areas apart from each other? A screenshot of your UI might be useful to show us.

Comment: "How do I move the onTap box?" - Possibly, wrapping the part you want to tap in the `Inkwell`?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem as you!
Put the `Stack` in a `container` and give it a certain width.

`Stack` It must have a certain size so that the widgets do not protrude from it.